# Gumstix Overo RTC support?

Tags: rtc, gumstix

I’m working on a design incorporating a Gumstix Overo AirSTORM-Y COM, and I note that it can accommodate a backup battery.  I understand that this is handled by the on-board TPS65950 PMIC, which includes a real-time clock module.

However, the Overo documents don’t mention an RTC, so I’m writing to find out if the RTC in the PMIC is functional on the AirSTORM-Y.  Is it?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the RTC in the AirSTORM-Y PMIC is functional. You can connect a backup battery to pin 52 on connector J1.

On the Gumstix Tobi board (https://store.gumstix.com/tobi.html), I've tested the RTC using one of these: https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=ML-621S%2FZTN

To read the RTC clock, you can use the linux userspace command: "sudo hwclock -r"

---

https://www.gumstix.com/images/overo_signals_latest.pdf

Looking at page 7, the Signal "VBACKUP" is what you're interested in - although, I agree, it's not made that clear it can be used for the RTC backup battery. Rest assured, it can be.

---

And just to be clear, J1 Pin 52 is directly connected to ball "M14", Signal "BKBAT" on the TPS65950.

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps65950.pdf

Comment: Thanks Michael, that's exactly what I needed to know!